# Comparing C#'s attributes and Java's marker interfaces

Tags: java, c#, interface, attributes

Yesterday I came across *attributes* in C#, the `[Serializable]` to be precise. As I understand it, they are used like metadata, to provide some information about your class.

Also, I learned that Java has *"marker interfaces"*, the ones with no methods, that serve the purpose of explaining the class, i.e. marking some characteristic of the class, for example the `Serializable` interface.

I was wondering: can you make a parallel between the two? Are they similar, or even the same?

Comment: I would say C# attributes are similar to Java annotations. Marker interfaces sometimes take on the role of annotations, because they existed before annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# attributes are more like Java annotations.  (I believe that's where Java got the idea.)

Marker interfaces are a Java 1.0 construct that are rarely used in new code, if ever.  I don't find them to be useful.  I would not recommend reviving the practice.

Java interfaces should be for separating declaration of method signatures ("what") from implementation ("how").  They should be like C++ pure virtual classes, not attributes or annotations.

Answer (score 2):

several years ago , Java didn't support attributes. Therefore, to "tag" a class or an interface so that 
they could be checked at runtime, you would use marker interfaces, 
which is basically an empty interface but you can still check if an instance can be casted to this interface.

`In .NET`, marker interfaces should not be used except for special use cases (such as allowing the use of extension methods),
 because attributes provide a better way to mark classes (and lots more) with metainformation. The same goes for Java 5 and newer,
 where annotations were introduced and should be used instead.

```
Marker interfaces:
```

1) are a bit easier to check for using dynamic type checks (´obj is IMarker´);

2) allowed for functional and data extensibility in the future (i.e. turning a “marker” interface into a “full” interface that actually declares some members);

3) can be used in generic type constraints;

```
Attributes:
```

provide a clearer separation of metadata;

allow for specifying additional information via their constructors or properties;

allow for multiple application to an entity;

are general-purpose in terms of applicability to different kinds of entities, not just classes;

It heavily depends on the particular application's architecture and design whether it's appropriate to use a marker interface or an attribute in a particular case.